# Transfer function gain

Tags: transfer-function, gain, frequency-response

\$H(s)\$ is the transfer function and we're looking for its magnitude gain. I went from the Laplace domain to the frequency domain by replacing \$s\$ with \$j\omega\$. However, the solution didn't match what I did.

[image]

They looked at the poles and zeroes. Please explain their process to me. Thanks.

Comment: "*I went from time domain to frequency domain by replacing S with jw.*", cool.

Comment: Poles cause s in the denominator to become 0, while Zeros cause s in the numerator to become zero. The transforms are in your class notes.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because homework should have an attempt at a solution

Answer (score 4):

The transfer function shown in the expression you gave must be rewritten to fit a *low-entropy* format. This format, described by the fast analytical circuits technique or [FACTs](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1119236371), will let you gain immediate insight on what the expression does. Here, your original expression is:

\$H(s)=200\frac{s+2}{s(s+20)}\$

Rewrite it by factoring 2 and 20 respectively in the numerator \$N(s)\$ and the denominator \$D(s)\$:

\$H(s)=\frac{200\times 2}{20}\frac{1+\frac{s}{2}}{s(1+\frac{s}{20})}=20\frac{1+\frac{s}{2}}{s(1+\frac{s}{20})}\$ which is the expression given as the answer. This expression can then be rewritten in an advantageous form such as \$H(s)=20\frac{1+\frac{s}{\omega_z}}{s(1+\frac{s}{\omega_p})}\$ in which \$\omega_z=2 \;rad/s\$ which is 318 mHz and \$\omega_p=20\;rad/s\$ which corresponds to \$\approx\$ 3.2 Hz.

The problem I have with this notation is that the leading term, 20, has the dimension of Hz and calling it a gain is improper to me. Furthermore, it has no physical meaning: this transfer function features a pole-zero pair associated with a pole at the origin. The coefficient of \$s\$ in the denominator is \$\frac{1}{20}\$ and has a dimension of time. To build the final transfer function, simply multiply the pole at the origin affected by its coefficient and the pole-zero pair as shown in the below graph:

[image]

You see the integrator response which crosses over at 3.2 Hz and the pole-zero pair response which "boosts" the phase between the zero and the pole. What is the significance of the 26-dB "gain" given in the formulated answer? None in my opinion. Actually, look below at the result when combining both responses:

[image]

You can see what is called a "type-2" compensator used in control system to boost the phase at the selected crossover frequency, usually where the phase peaks. What matters here is the realization of the so-called mid-band gain occurring around 1 Hz. It is 10 dB, not 26 as given in the correction. How can we unveil it? Simply by using what is called an inverted zero: factor \$\frac{s}{2}\$ in the numerator and simplify the leading term. You have:

\$H(s)=20\frac{1+\frac{s}{2}}{s(1+\frac{s}{20})}=\frac{20}{s}\frac{s}{2}\frac{1+\frac{2}{s}}{1+\frac{s}{20}}=H_0\frac{1+\frac{\omega_z}{s}}{1+\frac{s}{\omega_p}}\$ where, this time, \$H_0=10\$ or 20 dB and has the dimension of a gain. This is the mid-band gain that appears at 1 Hz. It is a design target and you have to design your compensator to a) match the required phase boost at crossover and b) adjust the mid-band gain to the right value. How can you do that easily with the given answer? This answer is mathematically correct but provides 0 insight on the compensator characteristics. Below is the corresponding Mathcad file.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Verbal Kint](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/350180/94854) has provided an excellent and thorough answer. Let me try to provide something that gives you a bit less of a cognitive leap.

You say "we're looking for its magnitude gain" but the expected answer is a single value. That demonstrates that your professor has not given everything you need to answer this question, and is instead expecting you to follow some specific process already taught.

In fact, the "magnitude gain" is a function of frequency. That is, the correct answer would be the magnitude of the transfer function: \$\sqrt{Re(H)^2 + Im(H)^2}\$ which if you were to evaluate would be an expression that contained frequency, \$\omega\$.

Neglecting that, the next most likely question intended is "what is the magnitude gain **at DC**". This particular gain value is so important that it might be excusable that the "at DC" part had been neglected.

Unfortunately this also leads to an issue - the transfer function has two poles `(s)` and `(s+20)`, one of which `(s)` is a pole at zero. Having a pole at zero means there is actually infinite gain at DC. Clearly this, again, is not the answer the professor is after.

Finally we see by the answer that the professor actually wanted the gain coefficient **when the transfer function is expressed with factors in terms of root natural frequencies**. There's a couple of things to note here:

1. The value out the front of the transfer function when in terms of root natural frequencies is usually called the "gain" because **when there is no pole at zero** it is equal to the DC gain. That's one of the benefits of expressing the function in that form - you can read the DC gain straight from the expression.
2. I've called this form "expressed with factors in terms of root natural frequencies". As far as I know there's no widely accepted technical term for this form. [Verbal Kint](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/350180/94854) called it a "Low-Entropy format", but that is a very general term for expressions that are "logically grouped", of which this form is an example. I used "expressed with factors in terms of root natural frequencies" because it's more explicit and because that's what you'll find used in the [Matlab documentation](https://au.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/zpk.html), which is often used to teach this subject.
3. This form is useful for various purposes (one being the FACTs techniques mentioned by @verbal-kint), but without knowing that form was required, the question cannot be answered correctly.

So back to your question - the reason they looked at poles and zeros is because they were interested in the major features of the transfer function **when expressed with factors in terms of root natural frequencies**. Those major features can be read straight from the expression - the poles, zeros and so called "gain".

Comment: Can you elaborate when you said the transfer function has a pole at zero? When we look for the zeroes, the denominator of s/20 is the pole at zero?

Comment: No, the other one: `(s)`. I've elaborated in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The way I understood it is that when you get a factor of, lets say (s+2) or (s+20) you divide out the constant.

ie: (s+2) = 2(s/2 + 1) , (s+20) = 20(s/20 + 1)

Here's an intermediate step in your example to make more sense of how to find the gain.

H(s) = (200 * 2(s/2 +1)) /  (s * 20(s/20 + 1)).

Here I substituted (s+2) = 2(s/2 + 1), and (s+20) = 20(s/20 + 1)

Then you can just take the factor in front and thats the gain.