In this transfer function equation, is "20" inside the log() the value that was factored out?
In the given problem, we're supposed to find the gain of the transfer function. The solution provides an equation to the problem. The question I have is, for that particular equation, is the value inside the log the "20" that was factored out from the original equation?



The problem makes no sense. The gain of the transfer function $|H(s)| $ is a function of $s = \sigma + j\omega$ and is not constant. In the solution they seem to convert the transfer function to Bode plot form and naively assign the constant term $20$ as the "magnitude gain". Please contact the author of the problem and solution and tell them they have no idea what they are doing.

@Andrew, Please post the source of the image.

Agree completely. The question is at best ambiguous. A request for the midband gain would have been unambiguous. ......... the question amounts to...what would be the answer if you think exactly like I do.

The ambiguity of the question itself aside, in the context of Bode plots/transfer functions the definition used for decibel (dB) is: $$20\log_{10}(x)$$

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/350070

When you write a transfer function, it is interesting to factor a leading term whose unit is that of the transfer function. It is not the case in the expression given as an answer and the factored term is not homogeneous to a unitless gain. It is mathematically correct but there is not much you can do design-wise. One final step is missing and that is where an inverted zero helps.
It is what I have done in the below illustration in which I have included units so that Mathcad can test the homogeneity of the expression:

All expressions are correct but in my expression, \$H_0\$ is a unitless mid-band gain of 20 dB while it is not in the expression given as an answer.

After posting this answer, I realized that Dirceu Rodrigues Jr kindly posted a link to an answer I already gave on SE a while ago : ) This new one is more compact and will hopefully teach how to write a transfer function the right way ^_^
